# jQuery is not picking up right value from php for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My `for` loop in php looks like this:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
 ?>
    <input type="hidden" class="ThisQuestion" id="GetQuestion-<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="VerySmallFont">
          <div class="SelectNumberBox <?php echo $NumberBoxClass; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></div>
    </a>
```

Now I want to extract value of `$i` from php to Jquery. Here's what I am doing in JS part for this -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".VerySmallFont").click(function(){
         var $Parent              = $(this).parent();                       
         var ThisQuestionNumber   = $Parent.find('[id^="GetQuestion-]:first').val();  
         var TestID        = $("#GetTestID").val();
         var ShowCQ = '1';
         $.ajax( {
             type : 'GET',
             url:'getquestiondata.php',
             data : {TestID: TestID, ShowCQ: ShowCQ, ThisQuestionNumber: ThisQuestionNumber},
             success:function(data) {
                 $("#LoadingImage").hide();
                 $('#ShowQuestion').html(data);
             }
         });
     });
 });
</script>
```

I'm not getting value of the var `ThisQuestion` in my JS. I also tried using the class `ThisQuestion` instead of id selector `GetQuestion` but that doesn't work either. I'm not sure what the mistake that I'm making is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon looking at your markup it seems you're pointing the wrong element. In your jquery you're pointing to the parent. You should point to the previous sibling which is the hidden input.

```
var hidden = $(this).prev(); // point the input
var ThisQuestionNumber = hidden.val();
```

Full:

```
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
 ?>
    <input type="hidden" class="ThisQuestion" id="GetQuestion-<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="VerySmallFont">
          <div class="SelectNumberBox <?php echo $NumberBoxClass; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></div>
    </a>
<?php } ?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".VerySmallFont").click(function(){

        var hidden = $(this).prev();
        var ThisQuestionNumber = hidden.val(); // point to the previous sibling
        var TestID = $("#GetTestID").val();
        var ShowCQ = '1';
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url:'getquestiondata.php',
            data : {TestID: TestID, ShowCQ: ShowCQ, ThisQuestionNumber: ThisQuestionNumber},
            success:function(data) {
                $("#LoadingImage").hide();
                $('#ShowQuestion').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yKzAdg)